# Android GCM Give Each Time new Registration Id for same device

Tags: android

i am tring to use push notification in my android project , when i start my application then GCM check for getRegistrationId() and it return empty where my device was register last time and GCM also given a registration id . why it do always request for register() when my device already registered .

```
  final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google can renew your id you have to update your new id on your application server to communicate with device

Answer (score 0):

In Android Developer Docs, it is clearly stated that

"Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your Android application with the understanding that the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called multiple times. Your Android application needs to be able to respond accordingly."

This answers your question.

Comment: thanks Nargis ji, but if i registered device once then how long time this key will be persist on GCM server to listen request from my own server corresponding to this key .

Comment: this only Google can answer :)